# How can use props text between React Components

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to appear text from main App.js to component via props.
 How can take Todos text from App.js to Modal Component in Modal Heading Text. Such as
**Are you sure? "and the name of Todo"**

**App.js**

```
import Todo from "./components/Todo";

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>My Todos</h1>
      <Todo text="Learn React" />
      <Todo text="Master React" />
      <Todo text="Explore the full React course" />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Modal Component Code**

```
function Modal(props){

    function cancelhandler(){
        props.onCancel();
    }

    function confirmlhandler(){
        props.onConfirm();
    }

    return (
        <div className="modal">
            <p>Are you sure?</p>
            <button className="btn btn--alt" onClick={cancelhandler}>Cancel</button>
            <button className="btn"  onClick={confirmlhandler}>Confirm</button>
        </div>
    );
}
export default Modal;
```

**Todo Component**

```
import Modal from './Modal';
import Backdrop from './Backdrop';

function Todo(props){

    return (
        <div className="card">
            <h2>{props.text}</h2>
            <div className="actions">
                <button className="btn">Delete</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
export default Todo;
```

Comment: Please share the code where `Modal` is mounted and how it's opened

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `text` from `Todo` to `Modal` as:

```
<Modal text={props.text} />
```

[`CODESANDBOX LINK`](https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-ishizaka-0mtl3g?file=/src/App.js)

and show it in `Modal` as:

```
<p>Are you sure you want to delete {props.text}?</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to pass this value.

1. By props:
   In **Todo** Component when declaring **Modal** Component you can pass variable

***components/Todo.jsx***

```
    <div className="card">
        <h2>{props.text}</h2>
        modalStatus ? <Modal headline={props.text} /> : null; // I have used state here to determine when modal shall be visible
        <div className="actions">
            <button className="btn">Delete</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

***components/Modal.jsx***

```
<div className="modal">
        <p>Are you sure? {props.headline}</p>
        <button className="btn btn--alt" onClick={cancelhandler}>Cancel</button>
        <button className="btn"  onClick={confirmlhandler}>Confirm</button>
    </div>
```

2. If you have a few components when you want to pass variables you should use useContext instead of props drilling.

***components/Todo.jsx***

```
import Modal from "./Modal";
import modalContext from "../contexts/modalContext";
import { useState } from "react";
function Todo(props) {
  const [modalOpen, setModalOpen] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div className="card">
      <h2>{props.text}</h2>
      <modalContext.Provider value={props.text}>
        {modalOpen ? <Modal /> : null}
      </modalContext.Provider>
      <div className="actions">
        <button className="btn">Delete</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default Todo;
```

***contexts/modalContext.jsx***

```
import { createContext } from "react";
const modalContext = createContext(null);

export { modalContext };
```